# Defining a non-resourceful route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to setup a non-resourceful route in rails but I dont know how. Rails api says the structure has to be like this. post `'post/:id' => 'posts#create_comment'` however, I'm not sure what I should exatly write.

I want it to post to the method "addbank" which is in the bankacctscontroller
I will be on the page localhost:3000/bankaccts/new

```
def addbank
  if (params['customer_uri'])
    current_user.customer_uri = (params['customer_uri'])
  end
  if current_user.save
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "bank account added"
  else
    render json: {error: "Payment account could not be configured properly"}, status: 401
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many formats for defining custom routes. The most elaborate one is:

`<METHOD> 'PATH' => 'Controller#Action', :as => path_helper_name` (:as is optional)

So for your problem it would be :

`post '/bankaccts/:id' => 'bankaccts#addbank'`

Answer (score 1):

If you use rails4.0,it will be written like this:

`get "/bankaccts/new", to: "bankaccts#new", as: :new_post`

I suggest you should learn rails routing first via the website "http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html"